# How to portray 'lifestyle' in an app logo

Tags: logo

I'm designing logo for an application titled 'Healthy Lifestyle'. The app provides info about restaurants with healthy food, gyms, some workout instructions; basically anything to do with healthy lifestyle.

I have some ideas to represent the 'healthy' part (e.g. the color green, leaf shape, etc). However, I am confused about how to portray 'lifestyle' in a logo. Any suggestions?

Comment: Logos do not have to be literal.

Comment: a (human) heart?

Comment: Per [the FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), brainstorming questions are discouraged.  Though you have accepted an answer, this question is now closed to avoid causing confusion for future askers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can show a flying couple in heart shape, natural leaf and much more please check link below nice lifestyle logo style.

http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-60500371/stock-vector-eco-illustration-of-green-people-embracing-the-earth.html

http://stocklogos.com/logos/search?keys=lifestyle

Comment: -1 for linking to stocklogos. ;)

Comment: what's wrong with stocklogos it's just for design inspiration..

Comment: it's a form of spec work which tends to be frowned upon by the industry. Spec work comes in different shades of evil, and perhaps this isn't the darkest shade, but there's so many better sites out there for logo inspiration than logo mills like that.

Comment: I'm not sure why linking to stocklogos should be frown upon, but then again I'm kinda new at this. The links gave me a couple of inspirations, thank you :D

Comment: I hadn't heard of stocklogos and I find the link pretty useful as basic inspiration, even with @DA01's caveats.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent it in many ways, for example a leaf shape, fruits, a person in the lotus position, or running, cheering... So many options to choose from (even combining them can work great!)

**Great logo inspiration can be found here:**
http://www.logofaves.com/ or
http://logopond.com/

Comment: I was looking for something that covers the whole thing, i.e. food, sports, etc. thanks anyway :)